# Cannot import pfx using Java

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, pfx, p12

I have a client certificate (pfx file), which I can easily import using the windows mmc, openssl and even Postman.
But when I try to import it to Burp or ZAP proxies, I get error message that the password is incorrect. I tried to manually import it using keytool CLI but no success.
I think this has something to do with the Java, as Burp and ZAP both written in Java, using keytool to handle the certificates.
I already reinstalled Java, downgraded it to an earlier version, and still failed with this.

Really need your help guys.

Comment: Do you mean `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore p12 ...` and did it say 'password' or `UnrecoverableKeyException` with cause ending `data isn't and object ID (data=48)` or `expecting object identifier for AES cipher`? If the latter it's encrypted with PBES2, which Java below 11.0.1 doesn't support at all and from there up only partially. Look with `openssl pkcs12 -info -in file` to confirm. If that's the problem, you can use `openssl pkcs12` to 'import' it and then `-export` back to a new PKCS12 using the more common schemes Java does support.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I get `keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect`/

Comment: `openssl pkcs12 -info in file` works, and shows the certificate attributes.
I already created a new p12 file using exporting the certificate and the private key using openssl, and it still does not work.

Comment: Still need help with this

Comment: Attributes are not the issue; the _encryption_ could have been, but not if you're not getting the specific exceptions I quoted. Are there any non-ASCII characters in your password (accented or non-Latin letters e.g. Greek Cyrillic Turkic Arabic etc, superscripts, fractions, etc)? Can you provide an example -- NOT a real key whose security matters -- demonstrating the problem (as hex or b64, or on pastebin or similar, to preserve the data)? (openssl can create base64 if you don't have other tools for it, as you might not on Windows.)